# How does Mask R-CNN automatically output a different number of objects on the image?

Tags: object-detection, semantic-segmentation, mask-rcnn, non-max-suppression

Recently, I was reading [Pytorch's official tutorial](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/intermediate/torchvision_tutorial.html) about Mask R-CNN.
When I run the code on colab, it turned out that it automatically outputs a different number of channels during prediction. If the image has 2 people on it, it would output a mask with the shape `2xHxW`. If the image has 3 people on it, it would output the mask with the shape `3xHxW`.

How does Mask R-CNN change the channels? Does it have a `for` loop inside it?

My guess is that it has region proposals and it outputs masks based on those regions, and then it thresholds them (it removes masks that have low probability prediction). Is this right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Object detection models usually generate multiple detections per object. Duplicates are removed in a post-processing step called [Non-Maximum Suppression (NMS)](https://arxiv.org/abs/2002.07662).

The `Pytorch` code that performs this post-processing is [called here](https://github.com/pytorch/vision/blob/5339e63148304ce32fd1cbd1e8bb74ea79458691/torchvision/models/detection/rpn.py#L356) in the `RegionProposalNetwork` class. The filtering [loop](https://github.com/pytorch/vision/blob/5339e63148304ce32fd1cbd1e8bb74ea79458691/torchvision/models/detection/rpn.py#L256-L279) you've mentioned performs the NMS and applies the `score_thresh` threshold (although it seems to be zero by default).